# WIX: is the Platform attribute of the Package element truly deprecated?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

If so, what is the appropriate way to specify an x64 build?

In my .wxs file, I have something like this:

```
<Package Description      ="$(var.pkgDescription)"
         Comments         ='Produced: Sun 17 April 2011'
         Manufacturer     ="Mfr name here"
         InstallerVersion ='200'
         Platform         ='$(var.Platform)'
         Compressed       ='yes' />
```

...where I use `-dPlatform=x64` on the candle.exe command line. This seems to work.

But, in the WIX3 documentation, it states that both the `Platform` attribute and the `Platforms` attribute are deprecated.  It does not describe what replaces them, or what developers should use in place of these.

[image]

When I remove the Platform attribute from the above element, and run the build, I get an ICE80 error:

> Product.wxs(285) : error LGHT0204 : ICE80: This package contains 64 bit component 'C.Textfiles' but the Template Summary Property does not contain Intel64 or x64.

It builds successfully if I use the `Platform` attribute, but because of the documentation, I am unsure if this is correct.

What is the proper way to build an x64 MSI??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package/@Platform isn't deprecated -- please open a bug on SourceForge so the doc can be fixed. But it's not necessary: See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/14/working-hard-or-hardly-working/.

Answer (score 5):

Refer the Documentation (WiX.CHM) included with the Wix distribution rather than the Sourceforge Documentation - you'll see that the *intel* and *intel64* values have been deprecated. Valid values are now *x86*, *x64* and *ia64*